# C# Getting System.DIINotFoundException in An Integration Test But Not When I'm Actually Running The App?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dll, dllimport, calling-convention

The weirdest thing here is that my app works perfectly. It's just that my integration test can't find the .dll or dylib file. I am using liboqs and my projects structure looks like this:

```
amaranth/
    Models, Controllers, Views, etc...
    oqs.dll
    liboqs.dylib
    liboqs.so
amaranth.Tests/
    IntegrationTests/
        AdminControllerTests.cs
```

The file that references the dll/dylib files is at `amaranth/Helpers/liboqsRelatedHelpers/Sig.cs and the part of that file that references the dll/dylib files looks like this:

```
        #region OQS native DLL functions
        [DllImport("oqs", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        extern private static IntPtr OQS_SIG_new(string method_name);

        [DllImport("oqs", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        extern private static int OQS_SIG_keypair(IntPtr sig, byte[] public_key, byte[] secret_key);

        [DllImport("oqs", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        extern private static int OQS_SIG_sign(IntPtr sig, byte[] signature, ref UIntPtr sig_len, byte[] message, int message_len, byte[] secret_key);

        [DllImport("oqs", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        extern private static int OQS_SIG_verify(IntPtr sig, byte[] message, int message_len, byte[] signature, int signature_len, byte[] public_key);

        [DllImport("oqs", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        extern private static void OQS_SIG_free(IntPtr sig);

        [DllImport("oqs", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        extern private static IntPtr OQS_SIG_alg_identifier(int index);

        [DllImport("oqs", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        extern private static int OQS_SIG_alg_count();

        [DllImport("oqs", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        extern private static int OQS_SIG_alg_is_enabled(string method_name);
        #endregion
```

This is what it looked like when I found the error in Visual Studio for Mac:
[image]

What could be causing these file's not to be referenced in the Integration Tests but allowing the files to be referenced in running the actual app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to copy the liboqs builds into `bin/Debug/net6.0/` of the `amaranth.Tests` directory. So the new project structure is:

```
amaranth/
    Models, Controllers, Views, etc...
    oqs.dll
    liboqs.dylib
    liboqs.so
amaranth.Tests/
    IntegrationTests/
        AdminControllerTests.cs
    bin/
        Debug/
            net6.0/
                oqs.dll
                liboqs.dylib
                liboqs.so
```